# Transactional replication Issue

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

I am getting this error when i try to create a new publicaton in dbserver-1 after reinstalling SQL Server in my database server 2.

```
Msg 18482, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Could not connect to server 'dbserver-2' because 'dbserver-1' is not defined as a remote server. Verify that you have specified the correct server name. .
```

I had replication of some tables enabled from dbserver-1 to dbserver-2 and it was working good.

Both dbserver-1 and dbserver-2 are in the same domain.

Comment: What code were you running that resulted in that error message?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Microsoft KB article:

[You receive an "Error 18482" error message when you try to make a remote procedure call (RPC) from one server to another in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/217395/you-receive-an-error-18482-error-message-when-you-try-to-make-a-remote)

Especially the very last part:

> You may receive this error message when installing replication because the installation process makes remote procedure calls between the servers involved in replication.

Since you mentioned that SQL Server was reinstalled, it's possible server names have gotten out of sync (depending on how the install was done).

I'd suggest following the troubleshooting steps in that KB.  In particular, make sure that `srvid` for the local server is "0" in `sys.sysservers` on both machines.